# inotify_event name empty in c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, inotify

I'm working on a C++ project with inotify on Ubuntu 22.04. For a simple inotify code like in the following:

```
int wd, fd = inotify_init();
    /* (0) Init inotify */
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("Unable to inizialize inotify()");
        return;
    }
    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/home/chao/Desktop/new_dir/", IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);
    if(wd < 0)
    {
        perror("");
        return;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
        int i, length = read(fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN);
        if (length < 0)
        {
            printf("Iwatch error");
            continue;
        }
        else
            i = 0;
        while (i < length)
        {
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)malloc(EVENT_SIZE);
            memset(event, 0, EVENT_SIZE);
            memcpy(event, &buffer[i], EVENT_SIZE);
            if (event->len)
            {
                if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                {
                    printf("Directory %s created/moved", event->name);
                    /* Nothing to do */
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("File %s is created/moved", event->name);
                    // handle files...
                }
            }
            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
    }
    inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);
    close(fd);
```

This piece of code on my ubuntu when used in a c++ file and compiled with g++(11.3),
`printf("File %s is created/moved", event->name);` doesn't print anything!
Instead in a c file and compiling with gcc (11.3) I can correctly get "File f_01 is created/moved" when I create a new file f_01 under /home/chao/Desktop/new_dir/.

Anybody could help me to understand that? Thank you!

Comment: The `inotify_event` structure ends with a flexible array member `char name[];` but you never allocate space for that (based on the value of the `len` member) -- you only allocate enough memory for the basic `inotify_event` itself and then copy the first EVENT_SIZE chars into it (I'm assuming `EVENT_SIZE` is basically `sizeof(inotify_event)` here).  Have a look at the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html#EXAMPLES) for correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
```

If you kept staring at this line, and continued to stare at it, eventually you would've figured out the bug all by yourself.

This is the actual size of each `read()` event. The size of each read event is variable. I suspect that you based your code by copying another implementation, from somewhere, that did this, but you didn't notice the significance of this line and what it means.

```
memcpy(event, &buffer[i], EVENT_SIZE);
```

But the code copies over only its fixed size, that excludes the name buffer. Hence you get nothing for a name. In fact you get undefined behavior, when the shown code pokes its nose into unallocated memory.

You will need to change the code that pulls out each event to `malloc` and `memcpy` the actual size of the event.

The shown code also neglects to `free()` the `malloc`ed buffer, and leaks memory. You must also fix this, too.

For extra credit, since this is Linux and gcc, some careful code-flinging can employ the services of a variable-length array, and avoid the need to `malloc` anything.

Comment: Hi Sam thanks for the reply! I just forgot to add the ```#define EVENT_SIZE sizeof(inotify_event)``` Actually the original piece of code I copied is ```struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&buffer[i]``` And no matter how it is, the point is in a .c file compiled with gcc I got the event->name printed out, whereas in a .cpp file compiled with g++ I don't. That's my problem....

Comment: I can only comment and discuss code that's shown, I cannot discuss code that's not shown, even if it's paraphrased. Code speaks louder than words and the shown code is defective for the stated reasons.